# BootStrap-5, Unable to see close-icon(cross)

Tags: bootstrap-5

I am unable to see the close-icon(cross). Instead i am seeing an another icon (on the extreme left before 'Success !') which is working though.
I am attaching screenshot of the output.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TppX3.jpg)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>BootStrap 5</title>
    <link  rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" > 
<body>
    <div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade-show' role='alert'>
        <button type="button" class="button-close" data-bs-dismiss='alert' aria-label="close" ></button>
        <strong>Success !</strong>
        Bootstrap 5 has installed successfully.
    </div>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Bootstrap JS should be placed above the code. (preferably in the head section)

Example : (based on Bootstrap 5)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show">
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
    <strong>Success!</strong> This alert box could indicate a successful or positive action.
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying kenobi. I have a question here, Does Bootstrap-4 has all features of Bootstrap-5?

Comment: Updated the answer with Bootstrap 5. :) Bootstrap 5 has extra set of features and is more optimized than BS 4.

Comment: Yes Kenobi, that updated code working fine.

Comment: Actually, there might be another error. You added unwanted hyphen for a class in alert `<div>`. It should be `class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show"` not `class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade-show"`.